# Taking data from formular and making a table, DOM, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

I have to take data from a form in `XHTML` and put it into a table.

Here is part of my HTML:

```
<form method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <label for="Title">Title:
                <input type="text" name="title" id="Title" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Autor">Autor:
                <input type="text" name="autor" id="Autor" />
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>Category:</p>
        <select name="cat" id="Cat" size="1">
            <option>Bestseller</option>
            <option>Novel</option>
            <option>Music</option>...</select>
        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="createNode()" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<table id="output"></table>
```

And the function in my JavaScript:

```
function createNode() {


        var title;
        var autor;
        var category;
        title = document.getElementById("Title").innerHTML;
        autor = document.getElementById("Autor").innerHTML;
        category = ...

        var in_table = document.getElementById("output");
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.setAttribute("class", "buch_neu");
        td.appendChild(title);
        td.appendchild(autor);
        td.appendChild(category);
        tr.appendChild(td);

        in_table = tr.parentNode;
        var last = in_tabelle.lastChild;
        in_table.insertAfter(tr, last);
    }
```

However, when I press the send button, nothing happens. After pressing `F12` there is an error "Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object,but actually that shoult be the scheme,isn`t it?

Comment: `createNode()` is return a function that's never executed

Comment: I put the points because in my code it stays the same as after autor and title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create and append separated elements, and you function should not return and anonymous function.

On top of that, your event listener shoud be moved in JS:

http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/8hg2uw57/1/

```
document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", createNode);

function createNode() {
    var title = document.getElementById("Title").value;;
    var autor = document.getElementById("Autor").value;
    var category = document.getElementById("Cat").value;
    var in_table = document.getElementById("output");

    var tr = insertNode("tr", {}, in_table);
    insertNode("td", {"class": "buch_neu", "text": title}, tr);
    insertNode("td", {"class": "buch_neu", "text": autor}, tr);
    insertNode("td", {"class": "buch_neu", "text": category}, tr);
    insertNode("tr", {}, in_table);
}
function insertNode(type, attrs, wrapper) {
    var node = document.createElement(type);
    wrapper.appendChild(node);
    for (var key in attrs) {
        if (key === "text") {
            node.innerHTML = attrs[key];
        } else {
            node.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
        }
    }
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are rescuing me!

Comment: @DianaPapukchieva Updated my answer with a better way

Comment: Thanks ten times for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you get

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type
>   'Node'.

because `title` and  `autor` are plain text not `Node` types, so you can't do this

```
        td.appendChild(title);
        td.appendchild(autor);
```

use `innerHTML` instead of `appendChild()`.